# Find solution for matrix B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A*B^{T}*A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
 8_{} & 0_{} & -1_{}\\ 
 11_{} & -6_{} & -3_{}\\ 
 -7_{} & 11_{} & 4_{}
 \end{pmatrix}$$

**Find matrix B**

After I transfer it to: $$B^{T}=A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
 8_{} & 0_{} & -1_{}\\ 
 11_{} & -6_{} & -3_{}\\ 
 -7_{} & 11_{} & 4_{}
 \end{pmatrix}A$$

Is it valid to transpose both sides of the equation, so I can get (possibly) the value of B?

Is this general direction for solving the problem, legit?

Comment: Hint: $(ABC)^T=C^TB^TA^T$

Comment: Do you have $A$ specified?

Comment: This looks correct, and yes, you can apply the transpose to both sides of the equation to solve for $B$, although your answer would be in terms of the matrix, $A$, unless you were given this.

Comment: ok thanks. Solved it

Answer (score 0):

Let right hand side of matrix be C. Eigen values of C are : 7.7, 0.42, -2.127. As they are distinct, C matrix is diagonalisable. So, $C = ADA^{-1}$

D is diagonal matrix with diagonal elements as eigen values. A is some non-singular matrix with columns as eigen vectors